# Different between CGLIB proxy and JDK proxy on Spring AOP perspective

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop, cglib, dynamic-proxy

[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-pointcut-tutorial) has this section:

> **this** limits matching to join points where the bean reference is an
> instance of the given type, while **target** limits matching to join
> points where the target object is an instance of the given type. The
> former works when Spring AOP creates a CGLIB-based proxy, and the
> latter is used when a JDK-based proxy is created. Suppose that the
> target class implements an interface:

```
public class FooDao implements BarDao {
    ...
}
```

> In this case, Spring AOP will use the JDK-based proxy, and we should
> use the target PCD because the proxied object will be an instance of
> the Proxy class and implement the BarDao interface:

```
@Pointcut("target(com.baeldung.pointcutadvice.dao.BarDao)")
```

> On the other hand, if FooDao doesn't implement any interface, or the
> proxyTargetClass property is set to true, then the proxied object will
> be a subclass of FooDao and we can use the this PCD:

```
@Pointcut("this(com.baeldung.pointcutadvice.dao.FooDao)")
```

I'm still confuse why **this** just works with CGLIB proxy and **target** just works with JDK proxy. Could you help to tell me the different between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the explanation in the tutorial does not make much sense:

- Both `this(MyInterface)` and `target(MyInterface)` work for JDK proxies, if the bean is declared as a `MyInterface` type.
- Both `this(MyClass)` and `target(MyClass)` work for CGLIB proxies, if the bean is declared as a `MyClass` type.

Just try, and you will see that I am right. In Spring AOP, there is not real difference between `this()` and `target()`, because due to its proxy-based nature, it implicitly only supports `execution()` pointcuts from AspectJ.

In native AspectJ however, you also have other pointcut types such as `call()`, and there you would see a difference: `this()` would match the caller's type, while `target()` would match the callee's type. E.g., if you intercept a method `A.a()` calling `B.b()` via pointcut `call(B.b())`, `this()` would return an `A` instance, while `target()` would return a `B` instance. Do not worry, if this is difficult to understand for you, because for Spring AOP and execution pointcuts it really does not matter.

The only subtle difference I noticed in Spring AOP is, that for `MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface`, pointcut `target(MyInterfaceImpl)` would actually match, while `this(MyInterfaceImpl)` would not. This is because for JDK proxies, the proxy actually extends `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, not `MyInterfaceImpl`. The proxy only delegates to a `MyInterfaceImpl` instance.

---

**Edit:** If you keep in mind that, in contrast to native AspectJ which involves no dynamic proxies, the semantics in Spring AOP are such that

- `this()` relates to the proxy object, while
- `target()` relates to the proxied object (proxy target),

it becomes clear why in this special case for JDK proxies `target()` matches, but `this()` does not.

Reference: [Spring manual, section "Declaring a pointcut - examples"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-examples):

> `this(com.xyz.service.AccountService)`: Any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the **proxy** implements the `AccountService` interface.
>
> `target(com.xyz.service.AccountService)`: Any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the **target object** implements the `AccountService` interface.

Only in this case, we are not asking for the interface class (which both the proxy and the target object implement), but for the implementation class itself.

---

Bottom line: For all intents and purposes, in normal use cases you can use either `this()` or `target()` for both JDK and CGLIB proxies. I recommend to stick with `target()`, because it best matches the implicit `execution()` semantics of Spring AOP, and usually you are interested in information about the target rather than about the proxy..

Comment: Thank for your reply. I want to make clear this point: "The only subtle difference I noticed in Spring AOP is, that for MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface, pointcut target(MyInterfaceImpl) would actually match, while this(MyInterfaceImpl) would not. This is because for JDK proxies, the proxy actually extends java.lang.reflect.Proxy, not MyInterfaceImpl. The proxy only delegates to a MyInterfaceImpl instance." As you said, finally the proxy delegates the call to MyInterfaceImpl, so MyInterfaceImpl get called, but why this(MyInterfaceImpl) does not match?

Comment: Because `this` is the interface class, not the delegate. You declare your bean as an interface type, don't you? Actually, I am even surprised that `target(MyInterfaceImpl)` matches. That must be a Spring-specific quirk, either intentional or by chance. I mostly use native AspectJ, which does not use any proxies and therefore does not need to delegate anything. So there the situation is clearer.

Comment: Your example is about this(MyInterfaceImpl) and target(MyInterfaceImpl), the implementation right? I'm confuse when you say "Because this is the interface class"

Comment: You declare or inject the bean as `MyInterface bean = appContext.getBean(MyInterface.class)` or so. For that bean, both `target(MyInterface)` and `this(MyInterface)`, but also `target(MyInterfaceImpl)` will match, but not `this(MyInterfaceImpl)`. Please do not confuse the bean declaration with the aspect or pointcut declaration. And please, don't just ask, but actually **try** by yourself. You will learn more that way. Nobody learns AOP by theory only.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your example and saw that everything work like you said. But I still need your help to understand why this(MyInterfaceImpl) does not match. I can understand that on the interface perspective (MyInterface), this(MyInterfaceImpl) will not match. But as you said finally the proxy will delegate to the actual implementation, so I assume that this(MyInterfaceImpl) will match later, but in fact it doesn't. The only different I see is, the method in MyInterface is called directly by me, while the actual method implementation in MyInterfaceImpl is called programmatically by proxy

Comment: This is why this(MyInterfaceImpl) will not match, is it correct?

Comment: I had a minute to consult the Spring manual and found a reasonable explanation - albeit only mentioned in passing in an examples section - for the behaviour we just discussed. Please see my update in the answer.